# Simple input validation in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to add input validation to a text box to make sure that if the user enter anything other than a number one of my labels will say "Input a number only." I have tried using an 'if' statement for this (look at code below) but it did not work. Instead of posting the message to "input a number" my program crashes with this error message

> 'System.FormatException': Input string was not in a correct format

I am a noob so I'm not sure how to fix this.

namespace Calculator
{
    public partial class frmCalculator : Form
    {
        public frmCalculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    string name = "";//Stores the Name typed into the text box
    string classType = "";//Stores the Class typed into the text box
    decimal grade;// Stores the Grade typed into the text box


    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        classType = txtBoxClass.Text;
        grade = Convert.ToDecimal(txtBoxGrade.Text);
        name = txtBoxName.Text;

        switch (classType)
        {
            //Case for Math class and grade comparison
            case "m":
            case "M":
                if (grade >= -1 && grade <= 100)
                {
                    if (grade >= 94)
                    {
                        lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is an A";
                    }
                    if (grade <= 93)
                    {
                        lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is an A-";
                    }
                    if (grade <= 89)
                    {
                        lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is a B+";
                    }
                    if (grade <= 86)
                    {
                        lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is an B";
                    }
                    if (grade <= 83)
                    {
                        lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is a B-";
                    }
                    if (grade <= 79)
                    {
                        lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is a C+";
                    }
                    if (grade <= 76)
                    {
                        lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is a C";
                    }
                    if (grade <= 73)
                    {
                        lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is a C-";
                    }
                    if (grade <= 69)
                    {
                        lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is a D";
                    }
                    if (grade < 65)
                    {
                        lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is an F";
                    }

                    //Clears the text boxes when the Submit button is clicked.
                    txtBoxName.Text = "";
                    txtBoxClass.Text = "";
                    txtBoxGrade.Text = "";
                }
                else { lblAnswer.Text = "Input a number!"; }
                break;

            //Case for Science class and grade comparison
            case "s":
            case "S":
                if (grade >= 94)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Science is an A";
                }
                if (grade <= 93)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Science is an A-";
                }
                if (grade <= 89)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Science is a B+";
                }
                if (grade <= 86)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Science is an B";
                }
                if (grade <= 83)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Science is a B-";
                }
                if (grade <= 79)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Science is a C+";
                }
                if (grade <= 76)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Science is a C";
                }
                if (grade <= 73)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Science is a C-";
                }
                if (grade <= 69)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Science is a D";
                }
                if (grade < 65)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = "'s grade in Science is an F";
                }

                //Clears the text boxes when the Submit button is clicked.
                txtBoxName.Text = "";
                txtBoxClass.Text = "";
                txtBoxGrade.Text = "";

                break;

            //Case for English class and grade comparison.
            case "e":
            case "E":
                if (grade >= 94)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in English is an A";
                }
                if (grade <= 93)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in English is an A-";
                }
                if (grade <= 89)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in English is a B+";
                }
                if (grade <= 86)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in English is an B";
                }
                if (grade <= 83)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in English is a B-";
                }
                if (grade <= 79)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in English is a C+";
                }
                if (grade <= 76)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in English is a C";
                }
                if (grade <= 73)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in English is a C-";
                }
                if (grade <= 69)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in English is a D";
                }
                if (grade < 65)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in English is an F";
                }

                //Clears the text boxes when the Submit button is clicked.
                txtBoxName.Text = "";
                txtBoxClass.Text = "";
                txtBoxGrade.Text = "";

                break;

            default:
                lblAnswer.Text = "Invalid Class type! Enter M for Math, S for Science or \nE for English only.";
                txtBoxClass.Text = "";//Clears just the Class text box.

                break;
    }

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Exits the application when the Exit button is clicked.
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Post more of your code.  Be sure to include the line that is throwing the exception.  I don't see anything in what you've posted that would throw a `FormatException`

Comment: @Amy Sorry, I posted the line that threw the error but it seems like it got cut off. Here's what's above the start of the 'Switch"                     `classType = txtBoxClass.Text;
 **grade = Convert.ToDecimal(txtBoxGrade.Text);** this is what throws the error
 name = txtBoxName.Text;`

Comment: Based on your comment, I'd say `txtBoxGrade.Text` can't be converted to a decimal.  What value does it contain in your watch window?

Comment: what type is `name`, `classtype` and `grade`?

Comment: @reds Yes. The only variable that I declared as a decimal is 'Grade'

Comment: If the user enter text that cannot be converted to a numeric value, that exception is the natural result. Use `Decimal.TryParse` instead, watch out for the return value and inform the user accordingly.

Comment: try { } catch (FormatException) { } anyone?

Comment: Thank you all for your willingness to help. The issue has now been solved by using 'TryParse'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx) methods of the numerical primitives to see if converting input to a number is possible.

```
decimal grade;
if (Decimal.TryParse(txtBoxGrade.Text, out grade)) {
    // Its a valid number - the rest of your code goes here
    // and uses the grade variable as the number you want.
} else {
    // Its not a valid number
    lblAnswer.Text = "Input a number only.";
}
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Decimal.TryParse` to check whether the input text is a decimal without throwing an exception if it is not.

```
if(Decimal.TryParse(txtBoxGrade.Text, out grade))
{
   // Your code
}
else
{
   lblAnswer.Text = "Input a number!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see if it is a number by using TryParse.

[MSDN Decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
decimal grade;
if(!decimal.TryParse(txtBoxGrade.Text, out grade))
{
     MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Unable to parse '{0}'.", txtBoxGrade.Text));
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below. You can make the below code more better. Anyway, keeping improvement as close to your code, there are couple of improvement you can make:-

1. Use of TryParse to check if grade is a valid decimal or not.
2. Use else if.
3. The condition if (grade > -1 && grade <= 100), now checks for decimal between 0 and 100. Earlier it was allowing -1 too. It that's your requirement then please change the condition accordingly.

Below code will assist you.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var classType = txtBoxClass.Text;
    var name = txtBoxName.Text;

    decimal grade;
    if (! decimal.TryParse(txtBoxGrade.Text, out grade))
    {
        lblAnswer.Text = "Input a number!";
        return;
    }            

    switch (classType)
    {
        //Case for Math class and grade comparison
        case "m":
        case "M":
            if (grade > -1 && grade <= 100)
            {
                if (grade >= 94)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is an A";
                }
                else if (grade <= 93)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is an A-";
                }
                else if (grade <= 89)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is a B+";
                }
                else if (grade <= 86)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is an B";
                }
                else if (grade <= 83)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is a B-";
                }
                else if (grade <= 79)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is a C+";
                }
                else if (grade <= 76)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is a C";
                }
                else if (grade <= 73)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is a C-";
                }
                else if (grade <= 69)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is a D";
                }
                else if (grade < 65)
                {
                    lblAnswer.Text = name + "'s grade in Math is an F";
                }

                //Clears the text boxes when the Submit button is clicked.
                txtBoxName.Text = "";
                txtBoxClass.Text = "";
                txtBoxGrade.Text = "";
            }
            else { lblAnswer.Text = "Input a number between 0 and 100!"; }
            break;
    }
}
```